# relation many to one between two entities in two bundles symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have two entities related with many to one relation but each one belongs to a bundle.
When forcing the update in the database I get the following error

```
the target -entity cannot xxxx\Bundle1\Entity be found in xxxx\bundle2\entity
```

Any ideas please??

Comment: Please be more specific. At least show us the relationship configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an entity extending xxxx\Bundle1\Entity in your xxxx\bundle2 and make the relationship between two xxxx\bundle2 entities.